# Angle in pendulum's motion

Tags: harmonic-oscillator

Let $\theta$ be the angle that a pendulum makes with the vertical. Is this $\theta$ the same as the $(\omega t+\delta)$ in $y=A\sin(\omega t+\delta)$?

Comment: $\theta$ (the angle to the vertical) is proportional to $y$, and in some treatments, *equal* to $y$. The angle (+) has a quite different meaning. This is basic stuff, for which you need study a textbook.

Comment: Your question suggests that this angle $\theta$ is constant, that it is the initial angle, corresponding to zero velocity. But at the same time that it changes with the time.

Answer (score 1):

A better way of mathematically describing the motion of the pendulum is by:

$$\theta(t)=\theta_0\sin(\omega t+\delta)$$

Where $\theta(t)$ is the *angle with the vertical in time* ($t$) and $\theta_0$ is the *initial angle (at $t=0$)*. This is unambiguous.

$\omega$ is the angular velocity:

$$\omega=2\pi f$$

where $f$ is the frequency of oscillation.

$\delta$ is a phase angle (often $=0$)

Answer (score 0):

No.

One easy way to tell: $\theta$ for a pendulum goes back and forth between two values, say, -20 degrees and 20 degrees. It is a physical angle.

$\theta$ in the formula is linearly proportional to $t$: $\theta = \omega t + \delta$. So as time ticks on, so does $\theta$.

Comment: *$θ$ in the formula is linearly proportional to $t: θ=ωt+δ$* That's a very confusing way of putting it.